# Link google sheet to html page

Tags: html, google-sheets

I need to link an editable google sheet to my html website so that any change in the sheet will automatically appears in my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of publish option on Google Drive docs files such as Sheets,Slides,Docs and embed them to your Webpages. You can find more information on how to do that here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965

Of course keep in mind that depending on what publishing option you select, you may have to change the access permission of your document/sheets.

Quick Edit:
If you're planning to just embed the sheet, make sure to select the embed option on the same publish to the web section that can be found by going to `File > Publish to the web`.

[image]